# How to save and update variables in a config file for a shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, python

I am working on something, and I have a peculiar requirement.

I have a scenario where I will have 3 variables defined in a file.  Every time a particular `jenkins` job is run, it would create a container environment using those variables.

I am thinking of initially setting these 3 variables to numbers, and they should be incremented each time, and should also be saved somewhere, so that on the next run the updated value would be used.

Comment: Can't you use a Jenkins build number or a Jenkins run number for that?  That would be much, much cleaner, architecturally.

Answer (score 2):

The following assumes that your config file with the variables is called `~/.myprogram.conf` and your shell script is called `myprogram`, and the variables are `var1`, `var2`, and `var3`.  Adjust this example to suit your real requirements:

The initial state of `~/.myprogram.conf` would be something like:

```
var1=1
var2=1000
export var3=5
```

This config file is a shell script fragment, so you can use `export var=value` if the variables need to be accessible to any external programs called by the script, as shown with `var3` above.

Your `myprogram` script would `source` that config file with the following somewhere before it needs to use the variables:

```
. ~/.myprogram.conf
```

when it needs to save the variables, i.e. after it has changed them, it can use `typeset -p` to dump the variables in a form that can be `source`-ed back into a shell script without any risk of weird quoting issues causing problems.  This works for any kind of variable, containing any values - string, integer, array, associative array.

```
typeset -p var1 var2 var3 > ~/.myprogram.conf
```

or the equivalent in bash:

```
declare -p var1 var2 var3 > ~/.myprogram.conf
```

(`bash` supports both `typeset` and `declare` as synonyms. Other shells, like `ksh` only understand the `typeset` variant)

**WARNING:** if another running instance of your program or any other program modifies `~/.myprogram.conf`, it will be overwritten at this point, losing any previous changes made by the other program(s).  This is mostly only important if you run multiple instances of your program at the same time.

You can use a lockfile to prevent simultaneous access if you need to (but remember to keep that lock for as short a time as possible to prevent any other programs from waiting too long)

e.g. with the sample conf file above, running the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

conf="~/.myprogram.conf"

. "$conf"

var1=$((var1 + 20))
var2=$((var2 * 2))
var3=$((var3 -5))

typeset -p var1 var2 var3 > "$conf"
```

would result in `~/myprogram.conf` containing:

```
declare -- var1="21"
declare -- var2="2000"
declare -x var3="0"
```

Note that the exported state of `var3` is remembered with `-x` rather than just `--`.